# Confusion about little-o and sums

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, analysis, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I was trying to do the following exercise from Apostol, Introduction to analytic number theory.

> Given two-real-valued functions S(x) and T(x) such that
>   $ T(x) = \sum_{n \leq x}S(\frac{x}{n}) $
>   If S(x) = O(x) and if c is a positive costant, prove that the relation
>   $ S(x) \sim cx $ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$
>   implies
>   $ T(x) \sim cxlogx $ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$

My idea is that even if S(x) behaves like cx at infinity, the sum T always calculate S near 1, where it can behave as it wants. I thought the following counterexample

$ S(x) = \begin{cases}
0  & \text{if x = 1} \\
\frac{x^2}{x-1}, & \text{if x > 1} \end{cases} $

$ S(x) \sim x $ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$

but if I take

$ x_k = k + 10^{-k}, k \in \mathbb N$

I have that

$T(x) \geq S(\frac{x_k}{k}) = \frac{(1+\frac{1}{k10^k})^2}{\frac{1}{k10^k}} \geq k10^k$

And so it's not true that

$T(x) \sim xlogx $ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$

Am I right? Nowhere the author claims that the functions need to be continuous (and usually in number theory they are not) nor bounded (maybe is this implicit?)*

I found on the web a solution in which the author use the identity

$ S(x) = cx + o(x) $

and then he inserts it inside the sum and gets

$ T(x) = \sum_{n \leq x}({c\frac{x}{n} + o(\frac{x}{n})})$

and then he gets the result; but I think this is not correct because the asymptotic equivalence works "as x goes to infinity" and not necessarily when x is small (for example when it is x/[x]). So I think he cannot "substitute into the sum". But also Apostol himself uses these substitutions in some proof in the book.

Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance

[EDIT]
*I mean bounded in every [0, M]

Comment: What it should be? I can't find the error

Answer (score 1):

If $S(2^a/(2b+1))=2^a$ when $a, b\in \Bbb N$ and $2^{a-1}<2b+1<2^a$ and $S(y)=y$ for $y>2$ then for $2\leq a\in \Bbb N$ and $x=2^a$ we have $$T(x)\geq \sum_{b=x/4}^{x/2-1} S(\frac {2^a}{2b+1})=2^{2a-1}=x^2/2.$$

So there is definitely something wrong with the main proposition. As you pointed out, the behavior of $S(x)$ for $x$ in some (small) nbhd of $1$ does matter.

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo . I just re-wrote my A.  So you may want to check your comment. As of now I'm too tired to respond.

Comment: I think it's still not working, because $2^a < 2b+1 < 2^{a+1}$ implies $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{2^a}{2b+1} < 1$ and this in the sum never happens since $n \leq x$ implies $\frac{x}{n} \geq 1$. Nevertheless I suppose that we can shift it in [1, 2], so that it will work. However, it seems to me that the problem is still the same: A is not bounded in some interval. What do you think about it?

Comment: I had a typo in  the 1st line. The intention is that  $S(x)=2^a$ when $1<x<2$ and $x$ is rational with numerator $2^a$........I think the result in the book is correct provided that we assume that  $S$ is bounded on  $ [1,1+r]$ for some $r>0 .$

Comment: Probably Apostol with S(x) = O(x) means |S(x)| < Cx for every x>0

Comment: Well that explains it. Others use $S(x)=O(x)$ to mean $\lim \sup_{x\to \infty}|S(x)/x|<\infty.$

Comment: In fact, this is the usual definition! It's unclear to me what definition Apostol uses